# System cannot find DTD reference by XSL

Tags: java, xslt

I am getting the below error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\rimancha\jarworkspace\XMLTransformJar\myDTD.dtd (The system
>   cannot find the file specified)

When I removed the tag in which DTD tag has defined then code is working fine. but I need dtd as well.

If I placed the DTD on the given path then in output xml some unwanted strings (from DTD )are getting appended which is not expected.

Please suggest what should I do here.

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete samples of XML, DTD, XSLT and Java code to reproduce the problem. In particular we can only fix "some unwanted strings (from DTD )are getting appended which is not expected" if you show us exactly with minimal but complete samples what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you want a DTD or you don't.

If you don't want to use a DTD then get rid of the reference to it. Having a reference to a DTD that doesn't exist is asking for trouble.

If you do want a DTD then you need to refer to it correctly (and note, the reference should be a URI, not a Windows filename), and then if the DTD defines default values for attributes, those defaults are going to be expanded in the document that the XML parser passes to the XSLT processor. If you don't want the defaults expanded then don't define them in the DTD. Some XML parsers / XSLT processors might allow you to suppress the expansion of default values - this depends on which products you are using.

Comment: When  I have run the xslt haing blank dtd then it is throwing error that premature end of file . Please suggest what should I do

Comment: XML experts in this situation would probably use an Oasis catalog to redirect the DTD reference but I'm a bit reluctant to recommend that because of your inexperience. You either need to put a minimal but valid DTD at the relevant location, or you need to get rid of the DTD reference in the instance document.